# Is there a way to create duplicated subcategory slugs on Wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, categories, slug

I've googled around for this like crazy, but can't seem to find a not too outdated answer for this question or something that actually works.

My problem is just like the one this guy describes on this forum post (from 4, holy *FOUR* years ago!):
https://wordpress.org/support/topic/duplicate-subcategory-slug-problem

I'm currently using the latest version, Wordpress 4.1 and what I'm trying to achieve is this:

Let's say I have 2 categories on my website, which are called **Boots** and **Shoes**.
Inside both of them, I want to make a category named **Red**. That's how my category structure would look like then:

```
 - Boots // -> URL: http://example.com/boots
 | ----- Red // -> URL: http://example.com/boots/red (GREAT!)

 - Shoes // -> URL: http://example.com/shoes
 | ----- Red // -> URL: http://example.com/shoes/red-shoes (cmon, wp, nooo !)
```

When what I'd like to achieve, is this:

```
 - Boots // -> URL: http://example.com/boots
 | ----- Red // -> URL: http://example.com/boots/red

 - Shoes // -> URL: http://example.com/shoes
 | ----- Red // -> URL: http://example.com/shoes/red
```

This way would be perfect !!!

In case you're wondering, yes, I know that's just part of wordpress and they don't want that to be changed, I understand why and all that jazz, yeah. 
But for this particular project, I really need this.

I guess I'll probably have to alter the core, not being able to update Wordpress if I do so, I know, but I have no problem with that if I need to.

But if there's another way to make up this hierarchy that doesn't involve categories and doesn't break my URIs, I can try that too. Any help or tip is appreciated guys, thank you very much !

Comment: Would the category nesting go any deeper than `shoes/red` (e.g. `shoes/red/running`)? If not, you could try implementing colors as a rewrite endpoint for `EP_CATEGORIES` or maybe `EP_ALL_ARCHIVES`. http://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_endpoint

Comment: It is possible that it can go further deep, yes. 

But let's say it doesn't. if I use that method, I'll have to add a line like that, using __add_rewrite_endpoint__ for every color, right ? 
Thanks for the quick comment, btw :)

Comment: Yes, every color. Narrowing down the color choices to minimum makes it easier for you and the site user too. ;) Remember, you need to use `template_include`, `template_redirect`, `pre_get_posts` or a similar hook to read the endpoint and filter your posts accordingly.

Comment: @ojrask Can you please post this as an answer later on ? 
I'm working on something else right now, but I'll give this a try later on. If it works as expected, I'll take your answer as accepted.

Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your subcategory structure doesn't go deeper than `shoes/red` (not `shoes/red/hiking` for instance), you can use [permalink endpoints](http://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_endpoint) to simulate categories. Permalink endpoints are rewritten from `domain.com/request/url/?endpoint`.

After each color or similar is set as an endpoint to `EP_CATEGORY`, category URLs can be suffixed with `/red`, `/blue` and so on. Applying the endpoints to `EP_ALL_ARCHIVES` allows the endpoints on CPT and date archives too.

Then in a filter or action such as `template_include` you can read the appended endpoint using the global `$wp_query` object and filter the category items accordingly.

**If** a user enters another suffix to the URL (e.g. `/red/hiking`), `$wp_query` will recognize them as a key/value pair as `red => hiking` (`?red=hiking` as a raw query string) in the query variables (`$wp_query -> get( 'red' );` returns `hiking`). This might be a good or a bad thing depending on how you implement the logic.

After you add permalink endpoints, you need to flush your installation's rewrite rules either using the function `flush_rewrite_rules()` or by going to the admin panel permalinks management section and pressing update once.

Note: You can't use dynamic names for endpoints. You need to define a static endpoint for each variant (red, blue, etc.).

Comment: I won't take this as the answer just because it wasn't the final solution for my issue, actually still have it... but thank you very much for taking your time, @ojrask, really appreciated to know more about endpoints, will probably have to use them in the future. So, +1 :)

Comment: No worries. Come back and post an answer in case you find something! :)

Answer (score 2):

I've had the same problem with my taxonomies and I've just fixed it, hope it helps.

First, you have your parents taxonomies and when you create the children you must be sure that the parent slug is added to the subcategorie slug. In your example it would look like:

- boots-red
- boots-blue
- shoes-red
- shoes-blue

This is to have a unique slug for each subcategory.

Now the important thing, the rewrite rules and and taxonomy links:

When you define the taxonomy, you should do this way:

```
register_taxonomy('mytaxonomy',array('mycustompost'), array(
    'hierarchical'      => true,
    'sort'              => true,
    'labels'            => $labels,
    'show_ui'           => true,
    'show_admin_column' => true,
    'query_var'         => true,
    'rewrite'     => array(
      'slug'        => '/%parent%'
    )
  ));
```

Also, you have to modify the permalinks so it has the structure that you need, if its a custom taxonomy (as my case) you do it with the term_link filter. My function looks like this:

```
function mytaxonomy_link( $permalink, $term, $taxonomy )
{
  if ( $taxonomy !== 'mytaxonomy'  && false === strpos( $permalink, '%parent%' ) )
      return $permalink;

  $temp_padre = $term->parent;
  $padre = get_term_by('id', $temp_padre, 'mytaxonomy');



  $cat_name = 'general';
  if(isset($padre) && !empty($padre))
  {
    $cat_name  = $padre->slug; 
    $termslug  = $term->slug;
    $new_slug  = str_replace( $cat_name , '' , $termslug);
    $new_slug  = ltrim($new_slug, '-');

    $permalink  = str_replace( '%parent%' , $cat_name , $permalink );
    $permalink  = str_replace( $termslug , $new_slug , $permalink );

  }

  return $permalink;    
}

add_filter( 'term_link', 'mytaxonomy_link', 10, 3 );
```

This function will transform the subcategory link into: http://example.com/boots/red

And the rewrite rule that makes all the magic:

```
  add_rewrite_rule('([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$', 'index.php?mytaxonomy=$matches[1]-$matches[2]','top');
  add_rewrite_rule('([^/]+)/([^/]+)', 'index.php?mytaxonomy=$matches[1]-$matches[2]','top');
```

In my case my posts / taxonomies relation was much more complicated but I think that this solution will help you.

Hope this helps because I've had a really awful time trying to get to the solution for this problem.

Comment: could this be applied to the default categories of the blog? So no custom post type but normal blog posts with categories like /boots/red and /shoes/red being "boots" and "shoes" categories in the default taxonomy. Do you think it's possible?

Comment: You only need the first rewrite rule. The /? part is the same as either with the slash or not. That's what the ? does, it makes it optional.

Answer (score 1):

In every problem there is the proper way to solve it, and any other *indirect* way...

It took me two days to figure this out in the proper way, so I'll add it here for anyone else that may need it in the future.

```
add_filter('wp_unique_term_slug', 'prevent_cat_suffix', 10, 3);
function prevent_cat_suffix($slug, $term, $original_slug)
{
    if ($term->post_type == 'product' && $term->parent !== 0) {
        return $original_slug;
    }

    return $slug;
}
```

As you can see in the code, I've narrowed it down to products only, but you can make it suitable for any other post type also by removing the `$term->post_type == 'product' &&` in the code above.

Comment: This does not work for me, could you add some extra explanation on how to implement this? See:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72057878/woocommerce-duplicate-category-child-slug-different-parent