# WooCommerce: duplicate category child slug, different parent

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

We have a WooCommerce site with 2 parent categories:
`New Furniture` and `Used Furniture`.

They both have a child category called `Chairs`.

**These are the URL's we get:**

`/new-furniture/chairs`

`/used-furniture/chairs-1`

I can't change the slug of `chairs-1` to `chairs`, why is this the case? And how would i fix this?

Comment: WordPress does not allow child categories/terms to have same name even tough they have a different parent.

Comment: You can change it but can't make is chairs as it was already exists in the system

Comment: @7uc1f3r I understand this, however i have seen WordPress sites doing this. There has to be a solution...

Comment: @RowanvanZijl I see there is a plugin for this with an alternative solution (The plugin detects URLs using its own algorithm, which is more advanced than the built-in permalink system) so it will indeed be possible. I should research it in detail because I can't answer it right away. I believe the answer to your question may require more focus on your part

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to solve for this recently and [responded to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78242269/3391302) with my solution, popping into this question with a matching answer since this is a more recent thread.

WordPress won't allow you to have duplicate term slugs in the same taxonomy, they need to be unique in the database. However, we can extend WordPress core to make the url structure work while maintaining the unique term slugs.

Using your example: `new-furniture/chairs` and `used-furniture/chairs` urls where `new-furniture_chairs` and `used-furniture_charis` are the unique child term slugs and their parent term slugs are `new-furniture` and `used-furniture`, respectively.

First, the rewrite rule:

```php
/**
 * Add custom rewrite rules for parent/child term urls.
 *
 * Adds a rewrite rule that will match terms 
 * that have their slug prefixed with the parent term
 * slug, separated by an underscore, but their url
 * is just the child term slug.
 */
function prefix_custom_hierarchical_taxonomy_rewrite_rules() {

    $tax_object = get_taxonomy( 'category' );

    if ( $tax_object ) {
        $tax_slug = $tax_object->rewrite['slug'];
        add_rewrite_rule(
            $tax_object->rewrite['slug'] . '/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?',
            'index.php?' . $tax_object->query_var . '=$matches[1]_$matches[2]',
            'top'
        );
    }
}
add_action( 'init', 'prefix_custom_hierarchical_taxonomy_rewrite_rules', 100 );
```

Then filter the `term_link` such that you remove the "parent_" part of the slug in the child term's link:

```php
/**
 * Filter the term link to handle hierarchical taxonomy permalinks.
 *
 * This will filter the term link to remove the parent term slug
 * from the child term url, so that the url is just the child term slug,
 * where the child term name is "parent_child" and the parent term name is "parent".
 *
 * @param string $link The term link
 * @param WP_Term $term The term object
 * @param string $taxonomy The taxonomy name
 * @return string
 */
function prefix_custom_term_link( $link, $term, $taxonomy ) {

    if ( $taxonomy !== 'category' ) {
        return $link;
    }

    // Get the parent term
    $parent_term = get_term( $term->parent, $taxonomy );

    if ( $parent_term && ! is_wp_error( $parent_term ) ) {
        // Remove the "parent_" prefix from the child term slug
        // to generate a url that looks like /parent/child/
        $link = str_replace( '/' . $term->slug, '/' . str_replace ( $parent_term->slug . '_', '', $term->slug ), $link );
    }

    return $link;
}
add_filter( 'term_link', 'prefix_custom_term_link', 10, 3 );
```

You may also want to filter the `parse_query` to check for any child terms that don't follow this structure. This avoids having to set *all* your child category slugs to the `parent_child` pattern, you can just apply it to those that have a "duplicated" url slug.

```php
/**
 * Parse the query to handle hierarchical taxonomy permalinks.
 *
 * This filter the query to check for terms that are child terms
 * yet do not have the parent term in the slug, thus the parent/child
 * structure should literally look for a "child" slug, not "parent_child"
 *
 * @param WP_Query $query The WP_Query instance (passed by reference)
 * @return void
 */
function prefix_custom_parse_query($query) {
    if ( isset( $query->query_vars['category_name'] ) ) {
        $slug = $query->query_vars['category_name'];
        if ( strpos( $slug, '_' ) !== false ) {
            list( $parent, $child ) = explode( '_', $slug, 2 );
            if ( ! term_exists( $slug, 'category' ) && term_exists( $child, 'category' ) ) {
                $query->query_vars['category_name'] = $child;
            }
        }
    }
}
add_action( 'parse_query', 'prefix_custom_parse_query' );
```

I've put this into a gist [here](https://gist.github.com/joshuadavidnelson/282614233c25071669f2502d77a7a8f9).

Notes:

- This only works with hierarchical taxonomies, this example is for the `category` taxonomy specifically. Update the taxonomy slug in the first two snippets and replace the `category_name` query var in the third one with the corresponding values for other taxonomies.
- Update the `prefix_` naming to something unique to your theme or plugin.
- This example uses a custom term slug for your child terms that follows a pattern like `{parent-slug}_{child-slug}`. You could change that to another separating character, but be careful to use a dash `-` as that is the default used by core when names are generated (spaces turn to dashes).
- This requires [the "pretty" permalinks](https://wordpress.org/documentation/article/customize-permalinks/#pretty-permalinks) where `/%postname%/` is set in the Settings > Permalinks.